# Hibernate does not persist and save object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, boot

I have a question for all the springboot and hibernate legends.. We have an object that we would like to save, so we use a persist statement. However somehow it doesn't really save the object in the database(h2). The hibernate logs don't really show an error. Does anyone recognize the exact problem we have here?

```
@Override
public void createInitialObjects() {
    System.out.println("Create initial objects initiated");
    //check whether the repo is empty
    List<Object> objects = this.findAll();
    if(objects.size() > 0) return;
    System.out.println("Configuring some initial objects");

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.println("Cabins are being created");
        //create and add a new object semi-random sample rate
        System.out.println("Try ID");
        // crashes on the em.persist if we use id=0L here;
        // I do not understand why hibernate cannot persist newly created cabins....
        Object object = Object.createSampleObject(-1L);
        System.out.println("ID success");
        this.save(object);
        System.out.println("save" + object);
    }
}

@Override
public Object findById(Long id) {
    return em.find(Object.class, id);
}

@Override
public Object save(Object object) {
    if (object.getId() == 0L) {
        System.out.println("logg save by save");
        // appears not to work on newly created cabins...
        em.persist(object);

    } else {
        // return the combined, merged object
        cabin = em.merge(object);
    }
    return object;
}
```

HIBERNATE LOG:

```
Hibernate: 
    call next value for cabin_sequence
save
Object{id=-1, type=SMALLODGE, numAvailable=4, description='colourful SmallDayTime objects, model 3', location='New York', image='/beachgear4.jpg', pricePerWeek=12}
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        object
        (description, image, location, num_available, price_per_week, type, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The hibernate logs did not throw an error and we tried different solutions but they actually did throw an error.

Comment: Normally, the transaction is flushed when the transaction is closed. I see no code wrt. transactionality. Have you tried calling `...persistAndFlush(...)` instead of `...persist(...)`?

Comment: This is a JPA repository and we are using the @Transactional tag, sadly persistAndFlush() does not imply here because we use the EntityManager

Comment: True, `...persistAndFlush(...)` was on `JPARepository`-level. But there should be a `...flush()`-method on the entity manger. Can you try calling this one after `...persist(...)` (This is not to fix the issue, but to diagnose the problem, I suspect that some exception should be thrown)?